# Stored procedure returning incorrect ID guid

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need a little help with this. The stored procedure below doesn't seem to ever match exiting unique identifier

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertUpdateThisStuff]
    @Id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
    @Content nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tAudit table (id uniqueidentifier)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myData] WHERE [ID] = @Id)
    --  UPDATE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[myData] 
        SET [ID] = @ID,
            [Content] = @Content
        OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @tAudit
        WHERE [ID] = @Id

        SELECT id FROM @tAudit
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --  INSERT
        SET @ID = NEWID()

        INSERT INTO [dbo].CBData ([ID], [Content])
        OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @tAudit
        VALUES(@Id, @Content)

        SELECT id FROM @tAudit
    END;

    SET @ID = (SELECT id FROM @tAudit);
END
```

the C#

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = (currentRecord.ID == null) ? Guid.Empty : currentRecord.ID;
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
currentRecord.ID = Guid.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value.ToString());
```

It seems the first IF statement does not ever become true, but if test (`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myData] WHERE [ID] = @Id`) with a the matching UID it comes back with data.

Comment: Yes  that is what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is problematic,,

```
 DECLARE @tAudit table (id uniqueidentifier)
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myData] WHERE [ID] = @Id)
    --  UPDATE
         BEGIN
```

`@id` is an Output Parameter  and is null by default and you are trying to check that..

basically `NEWID()` won't be duplicated,so update part is redundant

Comment: So why does it not recognize the inxoming data from @ID? How would I mitigate this? Should I use another variable for the outgoing data to @ID or is there another best practice to handle this issue.

Comment: you are not passing anything,if the intention is to check if newid() which you are going to insert exists,you can ignore that

Comment: The intent was to test the contents of @ID to see if it exists in the database then update if it exists and insert if it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

How are you declaring the parameter in your code? Is it `ParameterDirection.Output`?

Try changing it to `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`. Your SQL looks okay. And you *can* pass an input value to a parameter declared as `OUTPUT` in your stored procedure. So maybe it's just that `ParameterDirection`.

You can also change this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myData] WHERE [ID] = @Id)
```

to

```
IF @Id IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myData] WHERE [ID] = @Id)
```

If your ID column isn't nullable then it's going to work the same either way. But this is a little more explicit, showing that it's recognized that @Id might be null because it's an OUTPUT parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fix. 
This is my new stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertUpdatemyData]
    @ID uniqueidentifier,
    @IDOut uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
    @CONTENT nvarchar(255)
AS

BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @tAudit table (outputID uniqueidentifier)
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myData] WHERE [ID] = @ID)
    --  UPDATE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[CBData] 
            SET     [ID] = @ID,
                    [Content] = @Content
            OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @tAudit
            WHERE [ID] = @ID
        SELECT outputID FROM @tAudit;
          END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
    --  INSERT
        INSERT INTO [dbo].myData
               ([ID],[Content])
            OUTPUT  inserted.[ID] INTO @tAudit
            VALUES(NEWID(),@Content);
            SELECT outputID FROM @tAudit
        END;
        set @IDOut = (SELECT outputID FROM @tAudit);
END
```

and the relative C#

```
 //Add Parameter for output to sql command then Change Direction of parameter 
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDOut", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Empty ;
 cmd.Parameters["@IDOut"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 currentRecord.ID = Guid.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@IDOut"].Value.ToString());
 cmd.Transaction.Commit();
```